# Template inheritance of the client-side in odoo 10

Tags: odoo, qweb, odoo-10

I want add a link for download a demo file, in the template base_import. The original template is it as show below:

```
<t t-name="ImportView">
    <t t-set="_id" t-value="_.uniqueId('export')"/>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="oe_import">
        <input type="hidden" name="csrf_token" t-att-value="csrf_token"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="session_id"
           t-att-value="widget.session.session_id"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="import_id"/>
        <div class="oe_import_box col-sm-9">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <p>Select a CSV or Excel file to import. <a href="https://www.odoo.com/documentation/user/10.0/general/base_import/import_faq.html" target="new" class="pull-right">Help</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="oe_import_file_show form-control" placeholder="No file chosen..."/>
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <label class="btn btn-primary" for="my-file-selector">
                    <input accept=".csv, .xls, .xlsx, .ods" id-attf-id="file_#{_id}"
                   name="file" id="my-file-selector" class="oe_import_file" type="file" style="display:none;"/>
                    Load File
                    </label>
                  </span>
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default oe_import_file_reload" disabled="disabled">Reload File</button>
                  </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- More code -->
        </div>
    </form>
</t>
```

The code that i write for link add is:

```
<t t-name="BaseImportCustom" t-extend="ImportView">
    <t t-jquery="form.oe_import" t-operation="append">
        <p><a href="https://path-to-file" target="new" class="pull-right">Download Demo</a></p>
    </t>
</t>
```

but this not show the link, Somebody know because not work? or if exist another way of do this

Answer (score 1):

1. First, could you double check if `xml` file was already declared in `__manifest__.py` of your new module ?
2. Second, You shouldn't add `t-name="BaseImportCustom"` in your extend view, i believe the issue comes from `t-name="BaseImportCustom"`, you can search all xml files in Odoo with the key "t-extend" and notice that there is no case that`"t-extend"` exist with `"t-name"`. I hope this is OK (not test yet)

> ```
>  <t t-extend="ImportView">
>     <t t-jquery="form.oe_import" t-operation="append">
>         <p><a href="https://path-to-file" target="new" class="pull-right">Download Demo</a></p>
>     </t>
> </t>
> ```